# How to set up client certificate for EAP-TLS so that Windows finds it?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, certificate, openssl, 802.1x

I am attempting to connect a Windows 10 Home machine to a WLAN secured with EAP-TLS.

At the point I've reached I always get a

```
"The user certificate required for the network can't be found on this computer."
```

error message in Event Viewer even though the certificate that should be used was imported into Personal Certificates on Local Computer.

It appears that the way to associate this intended client certificate with the network connection is not via the profile XML file but has something to do with the SubjectAltName in the certificate.

I have tried something like

```
cat > $CLIENTCERT.v3.ext << EOF
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
subjectAltName = otherName:msUPN;UTF8:machine/first last
EOF
```

as `extfile` while generating the certificate with OpenSSL, but that didn't work.

How do I need to set up the client certificate so that it'll be found and used by Windows?

Comment: Does the network profile specifically require a _computer_ certificate? Your error message says otherwise.

Comment: No, which is why the certificate was imported into "personal certificates", albeit under "local computer" as that's where I was told it should go.

Comment: But that makes it the _computer account's_ (i.e. the 'SYSTEM' account's) "personal" certificate, not the user's. What happens if you import it into the user's own certificate store?

Comment: After removing the certificate from machine wide personal certificates and installing it for the current user the error message changes to "A certificate could not be found that can be used with this Extensible Authentication Protocol."

Comment: @u1686_grawity Not just the error message changed, it didn't even attempt to connect to the network. Previously I would see the EAP Identity Response on the EAP server and the error would come after the EAP Start TLS message from the server to the Windows machine.

Comment: There are good instructions in the PDF [Windows 10 EAP TLS Configuration](https://www.kaplansoft.com/tekradius/Docs/Windows10EAP-TLSConfiguration.pdf). Note the part that says "you will need to import the **CA certificate** to the Windows 10 computer and make sure that it is enabled as a **Trusted Root Certification Authority** in the Windows Certificate Store."

Comment: The local user certificates should get imported into `certmgr.msc` > personal > Certificates. The SubjectAltName of the certificate depends on the server-side EAP policy settings (some require it to match the username, and others don't use it at all). Make sure windows shows the certificate as Valid, and that you have the private key, like: https://imgur.com/JqTf4Jt

Comment: @harrymc The CA certificate was imported correctly and appears to not be the problem.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale After adding the private key things look better, thanks for that suggestion! However ONLY when installing the client certificate under "local computer - personal", it's NOT picked up from "current user - personal".

Answer (score 0):

This worked on my Windows 10 Home machine, no domain controller or active directory.

In this case `OwnCA.key` and `OwnCA.crt` are from a self-signed root CA used for testing.

```
openssl req -new -nodes -out client.csr -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout client.key -subj '/CN=WindozeX/C=AT/ST=NO/L=Zwettl/O=UL'

cat > client.v3.ext << EOF
extendedKeyUsage = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
EOF

openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA OwnCA.crt -CAkey OwnCA.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 5000 -sha256 -extfile client.v3.ext
openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt -certfile OwnCA.crt
```

According to some Microsoft documention the `subjectAltName` has to be set to the UPN of the user. On my machine `whoami /upn` gives an error and the client certifiate worked without this extended attribute.

The file `client.pfx` is the one that needs to be imported into the "Personal" section of the "Local Machine" certificate store using `certlm.msc` which, like everything else, I did as `admin` user.